# Access PATH variable from Gradle?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

In my `~/.bash_profile` I have:

```
export J2OBJC_HOME=/Applications/J2Objc/j2objc-0.9.7b
export PATH=$PATH:$J2OBJC_HOME
```

From the command line on my MAC I can do:

```
echo $J2OBJC_HOME
```

this reports:

```
/Applications/J2Objc/j2objc-0.9.7b
```

**How can I access `J2OBJC_HOME` from within gradle?**

Comment: try to use this  in your gradle script $System.env.PATH

Comment: No the result is ``/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin``. That is not what I want.

Comment: then your gradle instance is not running on the environment you think

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Restart your terminal or bash. And kill/restart the Gradle daemon if you are using gradle in deamon mode.

Comment: Still this does not help.

Comment: How are you running this?  From inside an app?  Does it work from the command line?

Comment: @tim_yates see my edit. I tried to access J2OBJC_HOME from within a build.gradle file.

Comment: How are you running gradle is what I meant?  From the command line or an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
System.getenv('J2OBJC_HOME')
```